# Can a client update details returned in a userinfo response?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, openid-provider

When a client retrieves details about a user via the userinfo endpoint, is the data returned meant to be view only? Does the openid protocol permit the client to update the details for the user or should that be done through the openid providers account admin pages only?

Answer (score 1):

The [userinfo endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) should support GET and POST request methods, but they both just return information about a user. The specification doesn't speak about the possibility to update the data.

An OpenID Connect server implementation can either keep the user data in its own storage or fetch it from a remote identity management system (IAM). So there can be an OpenID Connect server implementation specific endpoint for updating the user data or the IAM server can provide some API. In both cases you will probably need a special OAuth2 scope to perform the update.